# #1005 - Can't create table '' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `api_user` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'User id',
  `firstname` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'First name',
  `lastname` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Last name',
  `email` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Email',
  `username` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Nickname',
  `api_key` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Api key',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'User record create date',
  `modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User record modify date',
  `lognum` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Quantity of log ins',
  `reload_acl_flag` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Refresh ACL flag',
  `is_active` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Account status',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Api Users';
```

Then I need to have **api session** table and CREATE the table this way:

```
CREATE TABLE `api_session` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'User id',
  `logdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Login date',
  `sessid` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Sessioin id',
  KEY `IDX_API_SESSION_USER_ID` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_API_SESSION_SESSID` (`sessid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_API_SESSION_USER_ID_API_USER_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `api_user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Api Sessions';
```

I get the error

## 1005 - Can't create table 'api_session' (errno: 150)

I have double check the foreign key and no error found.
Its already 5 hours I cant figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

When the boss (https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/lvaro-g-vicario) told me to run this

`SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS`

I get this

```
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
140120 16:08:47 Error in foreign key constraint of table api_session:
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `api_user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Api Sessions':
Cannot resolve table name close to:
(`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Api Sessions'
```

How this happen?

Comment: My answer before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731346/mysql-error-code-1005/3731788#3731788

Comment: Works for me like a charm: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9cc4

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Can you see further info if you run `SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS`?

Comment: Please note that you can edit questions. Code in comments is hard to read. Whatever, **Cannot resolve table name** suggests you do *not*  have any `api_user` table at all :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the *actual* error message if you issue the following query:

```
SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS
```

The only way to reproduce this:

```
Cannot resolve table name close to:
 (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Api Sessions'
```

... is not having a `api_user` table at all.

I suspect you're issuing your second query on a different database.

Comment: I have api_user table on same database as what I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes i just triple check on that. How can it works in sqlfiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9cc4

Comment: So `SHOW CREATE TABLE api_user` returns the table code rather than an error message?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, you are right..  in Spanish is "Sí, tienes razón" ; I was in different DATABASE. - lack of sleep ;( code for rice. Boss, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help some people in the future find this question page:

The very same error message is given by mysql when the problem is that the foreign key referenced table is not using InnoDB engine but MyISAM.